# graph and find symmetry in this equation $y = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)$

Tags: calculus

I need the graph and find symmetry in this equation :

$$ y =  \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)   $$

Could you show me the steps ?

Answer (score 2):

We know that $\tan(\alpha)=0$ happens when $\alpha=k\pi$, where $k$ is any integer. If, then, you set $\alpha=\pi/x$ (as in your case), we see that

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)=0 \implies x=\frac{1}{k}, k\in\mathbb{Z},k\ne0$$

That's clue number one.

For clue number two, we can find the critical points of the graph (points where the slope of the graph is horizontal). Well  $\dfrac{d}{dt}\tan(\alpha)=\sec^2(\alpha)\cdot\alpha '$, so if we once again set $\alpha=\pi/x$, we see that

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\right) = \sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\cdot\left(-\frac{\pi}{x^2}\right)$$

Setting this equal to $0$, we can find the critical points.

$$\sec^2\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)\cdot\left(-\frac{\pi}{x^2}\right)=\frac{-\pi}{x^2\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)}$$

Oh no! It looks like there are technically no critical points, but if this above expression tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to a certain value, we can say that it approaches a 'critical point'. Another way of saying this is that the denominator must tend to infinity - but if you look at the denominator ($x^2\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{x}\right)$), that will only tend to infinity if $x$ tends to infinity.

If, however, the denominator tends to $0$, we'll be getting closer to a vertical asymptote (slope approaches positive or negative infinity). This one is tricky, because you must not forget the $-\pi$ in the numerator. Now taking that into, consideration, we can certainly say that the denominator will be equal to $0$ at $x=\dfrac{2}{1+2k}$, where $k$ is an integer. Why? Because if you plug it into $\cos^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{x}\right)$, you'll get zero. Additionally, the slope will always be negative! This is because $x^2$ and $\cos^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{x}\right)$ are always positive, so the $-\pi$ term in the numerator will always win out.

And that's the second clue.

With all that said, we can make an attempt at the graph for the function.

[image: msepic2]

Not so bad, eh?

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: Would you (pretty please) accept this answer if you felt it was sufficient?